# Java program involving substring() and charAt() methods

Tags: java, loops, methods, substring, charat

My program is supposed to print out the initials of the name and print the last name. 
Eg. if the name entered is Mohan Das Karamchand Gandhi, the output must be MDK Gandhi. Although I get a "String index out of range" exception.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class name {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String w=s.nextLine();
    int l=w.length();
    char ch=0; int space=0;int spacel = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        ch=w.charAt(i);
        if(ch==32||ch==' '){
            space+=1;
            spacel=i+1;
            System.out.print(w.charAt(spacel) + " ");
        }            
    }
    System.out.println(w.substring(spacel,l+1));
}
```

Comment: Please read again the documentation for `String.substring(int, int)`

Comment: Any reason you're not using `lastIndexOf`?

Comment: Which is the current output?

Comment: Also note that your condition should just be `if (ch == ' ')` - the two conditions you've got at the moment are equivalent...

Comment: At least that you are using the very same format for name + last name, I think you should split it into two different strings, since you cannot know if the person has just one name or more.

Comment: Don't be afraid to have names that are easy to understand, otherwise your code is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is the culprit:

```
        spacel=i+1;
        System.out.print(w.charAt(spacel) + " ");
```

When `i` is equal to `l - 1`, then `space1` is going to be equal to `l` or `w.length()`, which is beyond the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using String's split() method or using StringTokenizer.

First split string using space as delimiter. Then according to your format last string would be Last Name and iterate over other string objects to get initial characters.

```
    String name = "Mohan Das Karamchand Gandhi";
    String broken[] = name.split(" ");
    int len = broken.length;
    char initials[] = new char[len-1];
    for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
        initials[i] = broken[i].charAt(0);
    }
    String finalAns = new String(initials)+" "+broken[len-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class name 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String w=s.nextLine();
    int l=w.length();
    char ch=0; int space=0;int spacel = 0;
    System.out.print(w.charAt(0) + " ");
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
    ch=w.charAt(i);
    if(ch==32||ch==' ')
    {
        space+=1;

        spacel=i+1;
        System.out.print(w.charAt(spacel) + " ");

    }            
    }
    System.out.println("\b\b"+w.substring(spacel,l));
    }
    }
```